# Написание Unit теста

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать unit тест на такой код:

```
public class DashboardResultGenerator
{
    public static DashboardResult GetResult(DashboardType dashboardType, Userconnection userconnection)
    {
        switch(dashboardType)
        {
            case DashboardType.CaseQueueSl:
            {
                return new CaseQueueSlResultGenerator().GetResult(dashboardType, userconnection);
            }
            case DashboardType.CaseQueueLcr:
            {
                return new CaseQueueLcrResultGenerator().GetResult(dashboardType, userconnection);
            }
        }

        return new DashboardResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Написать n методов для n `case`. Либо один с n количеством Assert

Comment: Ну можно в принципе используя `Mock`-и заменить обманками всё подряд что внутри используется, кроме входного параметра типа `DashboardType`, и проверить потом вызывая метод с разными `DashboardType`, что возвращается результат нужного типа.

Comment: Очень странно, что в методе во внутренние генераторы пробрасывается dashboardType. Вопрос: а зачем это делать, если судя по названию классов, каждый класс сам знает про свой dashboardType. (Возможно, не по теме, но поскольку вы пишете тесты на этот код, то мой комментарий может быть полезным)

Comment: Код надо вставлять текстом, а не картинкой.

Answer (score 2):

Юнит-тесты под код не пишут. Юнит-тесты пишут под исходные требования и ограничения.

Судя по всему, какие изначально требования и ограничения ставились при написании приведенного вами кода вы не знаете... Соответственно, вам предстоит трудоемкая задача - заняться реверсингом требований и ограничений к этому куску кода, ко всем вызываемым в нем методам(здесь - `CaseQueueLcrResultGenerator::GetResult()` и все что вызывается глубже..), ко всем участкам кода вызывающих этот код...

Нужно досконально разобраться в том,  зачем он вообще был написан. Получится что-то вроде:

Для того что бы <здесь описать необходимость применения метода GetResult в других классах>, необходим метод, который должен:

1. В зависимости от значения параметра `dashbordType`, должен вызывается метод GetResult() из новых экземпляров классов(<описать почему важно всегда создавать новые экземпляры этих классов>) `CaseQueueSlResultGenerator` либо `CaseQueueLcrResultGenerator`, получая на выходе <что должны получить?>
2. В зависимости от значения полей в объекте переданном в параметре `userConnection` должны на выходе получить <что именно?>
3. При определенных "хитрых" сочетаниях `dashbordType` и `userConnection` должны на выходе получить <что?>
4. Если значение параметра `dashbordType` не поддерживается, то должен возвращаются пустой результат..

Ну и дальше уже можно тривиально написать юнит-тест - просто написав каждое требование или ограничение в виде отдельного тест-кейса..